# Send animated emoji through dms discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have seen many discord bot dming me using an animated emoji. I understood how to send animated emojis in a server because the emojis are in the server. But how can they send a dm me with an animated emoji? I want to send a dm when a user does !verify, the bot replies to the dm saying: "You have been verified!" with an emoji.

```py
@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    helpembed=discord.Embed(title="Verification", url=" ", description="You have been verified!", color=discord.Color.blue())
    await ctx.author.send(embed=helpembed)
```

Comment: Each emoji has an id. That's how discord differentiates it, even if multiple servers have the same named emojis or you want to send emoji from another server in there. Once you have that id - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_emoji#discord.Client.get_emoji

Comment: Bots can send any emoji from server's that they're in. They're like users with nitro in the sense that they can send emojis from any server, animated included, anywhere. All you need to do is have a server that the bot is in that has an animated emoji in it and then send it in the dms using the id method that h4z3 just mentioned.

Comment: ok, is this the correct id method?

@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx):
    emoji = bot.get_emoji('786276426839752714')
    await ctx.author.send(emoji)

Comment: @saaasaa id's should be integers not strings

Answer (score 1):

Discord uses a special pattern for custom and animated emojis (like it does with channel mentions and user mentions).

```py
animated_emoji = "<a:emoji_name:emoji_id>"
custom_emoji = "<:emoji_name:emoji_id>"
```

If you have the emoji id, this will work for custom and animated emojis:
([client.get_emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_emoji#discord.Client.get_emoji))

```py
emoji = bot.get_emoji(emoji_id)
await ctx.send("Hello! {}".format(emoji))
```

If you have its name *and* the guild the emoji is from: ([utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get), [guild.emojis](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20emojis#discord.Guild.emojis))

```py
from discord import utils

emoji = utils.get(guild.emojis, name="my emoji name")
await ctx.send("Hello! {}".format(emoji))
```

References:

- [discord.Emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20emoji#discord.Emoji)
- [client.get_emoji](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_emoji#discord.Client.get_emoji)
- [guild.emojis](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20emojis#discord.Guild.emojis)
- [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get)